# class not found exception with Google Guice

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, guice

I'm trying to start my first app with Java and Google Guice.  Best I am able to find else where on the web has not been able to address my question.   When I run my java app from the console I get the following error:

```
matt@linux ~/dev/options/console/target $ java -jar ServerConsole-R1.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Module
    at Application.Startup.main(Startup.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Module
```

I have google guice referenced in my pom file.   Maven gives no errors when I call mvn -compile or mvn -install.  I checked the local maven respository directory and it has downloaded the guice jar files.

My pom file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tatmancapital</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServerConsole</artifactId>
    <version>R1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
           <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
          <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>               
                <mainClass>Application.Startup</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>        
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I cracked open the jar file and compared it to a spring boot project jar file and I find a missing folder in the jar file called: BOOT-INF.

It seems like I have all the references correct.  But the build output is missing the supporting jar files.

What is missing?

Thnx
Matt

Comment: could you try - updating `com.google.inject:guice` to `4.1.0` and creating a jar using `mvn package`

Comment: same results.  the output Jar file is barely 4K and only contains my app code.

Comment: 4K seems too small. Also not sure about `jar-plugin`. We have packaged using `shade plugin`. Seems to be working fine for us. Could you share the module directory structure as well please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by module directory structure.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I meant the class package and directory within the module.

Comment: So you gave me an idea since you mentioned you used a different plugin.  I searched for another plugin and went with maven-assembly-plugin.  That got it working.  I have a terrible package name as it postfixes jar-with-dependencies to the jar name.   But it works!  Thank you helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a different package.

My new pom file looks like this ( I also removed unused dependencies shown above, but that change did not resolve my problem):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tatmancapital</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServerConsole</artifactId>
    <version>R1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>     
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>            
                    <mainClass>Application.Startup</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>       
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

That gave me an executable JAR file.  Thank you @nullpointer.

The jar file name is horrendous.  Using the package name member for the manifest didnt affect it.

M

Answer (score 0):

With this pom in target/ you must have two different jars, ServerConsole-R1.jar and ServerConsole-R1-jar-with-dependencies.jar, try to execute second

First small jar can be executed via 'mvn java:exec' that add all necessary classpaths